# ЧИТАЕМЫЙ и ЧИТАБЕЛЬНЫЙ — в чём разница?

Tags: значение-слов, выбор-слов, неологизмы

В словаре русского языка (том IV, 1961) слова ***читабельный*** нет, есть только *читаемость*, ***читаемый***; в Орфографическом словаре (2003) "читабельный" уже присутствует.
Означает ли это, что слово появилось не так давно? Можно ли отнести его к неологизмам?

Почерк, текст, сайт, книга — они какие: **читаемые** или **читабельные**?
КАК правильно? Есть ли разница и особенности употребления?

Comment: Т .е. суффикс "абель" соответствуют английском суффиксу able. Основное значение суффикса: ***СПОСОБНОСТЬ и ВОЗМОЖНОСТЬ***. Часто переводится: начиная со слов «который можно» + инфинитив. Читабельный -readable  ***(тот, который можно читать)***. Ср. другие слова в русском:  ***Транспортабельный***- такой, который (которого) ***можно перевозить, транспортировать***;  ***Операбельный*** -такой, который ***может быть прооперирован**  который может перенести хирургическую операцию.

Comment: Читабельный почерк - такой, который ***может быть прочитан***.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 5):

У Кузнецова и Ефремовой оба прилагательных — читаемый (популярный) и читабельный — даны как **разговорные**, видимо, в литературный язык они ещё не вошли.

*Читабельный* — неологизм, как и все с заимствованным суффиксом **-абельн-**: кликабельный, читабельный, коммуникабельный, респектабельный, презентабельный,
рентабельный, транспортабельный, комфортабельный, фешенебельный, операбельный. Но воспринимаются все слова с этим суффиксом  не как разговорные, а скорее как термины.
Я это слово как-то сразу не приняла, но до него употребляла "удобочитаемый", оно мне тоже не нравилось, пусть уж "читабельный" тогда, если лень сказать "легко читаемый".

*Читаемый* — **разговорное** значение "популярный". Чаще всё-таки слово употребляется как страдательное причастие — читаемый многими.
Но язык развивается, действует закон экономии средств языка, вместо двух слов говорят одно, появляется новое значение. От этого не уйти.

Comment: Людмила, в словаре Кузнецова - это на Грамоте? Там слова "читаемый" вроде нет, только в РОС. Грамота советует вместо нечитабельный употреблять -нечитаемый( как более литературный вариант). Хотя в словарях этого значения у слова "читаемый" мне не удалось найти.

Answer (score 1):

"Читабельный", может, и давно появилось, а вот "смотрибельный" – точно недавно. Смысл тот же самый – такой, который можно читать (смотреть).

– Как фильм (книга)?

– Да ничего, смотреть (читать) можно. 
(Сейчас бы сказали: "смотрибельный" или "читабельная")

А вот почерк "читабельным" быть не может – просто так не говорят. Как и телевизор не может быть смотрибельный.

Comment: Стирабельный - тоже новое "словечко". Употребляется вовсю.

Comment: Читабельным почерк быть очень даже может! Если недостаточно моего свидетельства, Гугл в помощь: https://goo.gl/mZR9vc.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "читабельный" зафиксировано в словаре Ушакова (1935-1940), Ефремовой, есть и у Кузнецова (словарь на Грамоте).

> ЧИТА́БЕЛЬНЫЙ -ая, -ое; -лен, -льна, -льно. *Разг*.
>   Такой, который читается легко, без затруднений или охотно многими.

Читаемый — популярный, распространенный среди читателей.

Почерк может быть только читабельным (т. е. легко читаемым); текст, сайт, книга — как читаемыми, так и читабельными.